# Maintaining a Secure MySQL connection

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm new to databases and all that stuff. Let's say I have an application that connects to a database to authenticate users. I have a table Students (the users) with their respective passwords. To connect to the database, in order to  I need a MySQL connection that looks like this :

MySqlConnection("server=; database=; uid=; pwd=");

The problem is the fact that I need to hard-code the root password of the database in the application, therefore distributing the root password of the database to all users of the application. To me, it doesn't make sense ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/webserver-security/

Comment: Create a limited user that just has permission to select from the Students table, no more. It is possible to extract the password from the compiled exe or dll, but it takes a little work, and it only leads to the limited user account. Depends how valuable the contents of this database are, and how valuable your time is.

Comment: I would Suggest to use web service as it will not provide direct  access of database to application.And you do not need to use password in application you can only store it in local web server.+1 for a good Question.

Answer (score 0):

In general you have something like 'client server model'. The client (your c# app), connects to the server. The server then connects to the DB (and so only on the server side the user/pass is known).

> client <-> server <-> mysql

I would say its bad practice to implement a db connection in the client. However, you could implement a per user database authorization. Meaning the client needs to enter (the mysql ) user/pass. But then you need to give the user certain 'rights' directly on the db. My guess is, you don't want that.